# Trouble setting up Ubuntu repositories for ROS

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I'm realativly new to the whole command line/terminal thing. So I was working through the instructions here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT/diamondback

I got to the step about the repositories and I'm not sure how to change them. I know it says to go to the Ubuntu page for help on doing this, but that link does not really provide me much help.

So if any one else has installed ROS for the NXT on Ubuntu would you be willing to share your information with me and help a newbie out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9548/trouble-setting-up-ubuntu-repositories-for-ros/) by [SnowRider04](https://answers.ros.org/users/345/snowrider04/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a lot of information on that page.  A simiple way to do this from their page is to use Synaptic.

1. From the main menu open: System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager
2. Inside Synaptic: Open Settings >> Repositories
3. Make sure that "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse" all have checkmarks next to them.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0